# Last Node Field for Iteration Path in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to find a file which stores last node for iteration path. For example, we have field for Area Path, called Node Name which shows the last node of Area Path.

**Example -**

Area Path - *Enterprise Business Applications\EBA Release\EBA HCM*

Node Name - *EBA HCM*

**Similar for Iteration Path** - *Enterprise Business Applications\EBA Release\Release - Jun '23*, I'm looking for a field which gives *Release - Jun '23*.